# Devise: Is it possible to NOT send a confirmation email in specific cases ? (even when confirmable is active)

Tags: ruby, email, devise, confirmation

Here is my situation, I use devise to allow users to create account on 
my site and manage their authentication. 
During the registration process I allow customers to change some 
options, leading to an actually different account being created but 
still based on the same core user resource. 
I would like to choose not to send a confirmation email for some of 
those account types. I don't care if the account do not get confirmed 
and user cannot log in, that's ok, no pb with that. 
How would I go about doing that ? 
Thanks, 
Alex

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually it's quite easy once I dig a little deeper.
Just override one method in your User model (or whatever you are using):

```
    # Callback to overwrite if confirmation is required or not.
    def confirmation_required?
      !confirmed?
    end
```

Put your conditions and job's done !

Alex

Comment: The mail won't be sent in an resend_confirmation or a send_reconfirmation, which are usefull ...

Answer (score 18):

If you just want to skip sending the email but not doing confirmation, use:

```
# Skips sending the confirmation/reconfirmation notification email after_create/after_update. Unlike
# #skip_confirmation!, record still requires confirmation.
@user.skip_confirmation_notification!
```

If you don't want to call this in your model with a callback overwrite this method:

```
def send_confirmation_notification?
  false
end
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also simply add the following line of code in your controller before creating the new user:

```
@user.skip_confirmation!
```

Comment: If you're overloading `create` action and using `super do |user|` for customization, it's too late to skip, devise already sent the email. This should go in `build_resource`, for instance.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if Devise added this after the other answers were submitted, but the code for this is right there in `confirmable.rb`:

```
  # If you don't want confirmation to be sent on create, neither a code
  # to be generated, call skip_confirmation!
  def skip_confirmation!
    self.confirmed_at = Time.now
  end
```

Comment: Note that you should call this before saving the user, otherwise the `Confirmation instructions` email will be sent.

Comment: There's also a similar `skip_reconfirmation!` method

Answer (score 6):

I was able to do something similar with the functions:

## registrations_controller.rb

```
def build_resource(*args)
    super
    if session[:omniauth] # TODO -- what about the case where they have a session, but are not logged in?
      @user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
      @user.mark_as_confirmed # we don't need to confirm the account if they are using external authentication
      # @user.valid?
    end
  end
```

And then in my user model:

## user.rb

```
  def mark_as_confirmed
    self.confirmation_token = nil
    self.confirmed_at = Time.now
  end
```